# Custom filtering With Button for Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Im using Datatable for my current project. In one of my table I have several columns. One of the column is `Status` column that will have one of three value `Open`, `Rejected`, and `Approved`. I want to filter record that shown in table with three button, `In Progress` and `Closed`, like this:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
    <button id="onprogress" class="btn btn-default filter">On Process</button>
    <button id="closed" class="btn btn-default filter">Closed</button>
    <button id="all" class="btn btn-default filter">All</button>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript code that i used:

```
var dataTables = $('#datatable').DataTable({
    "info": false,
    "lengthChange": false
});

$('#all').on('click', function () {
    dataTables.columns(4).search("").draw();
});

$('#onprogress').on('click', function () {
    dataTables.columns(4).search("Open" ).draw();
}); 

$('#closed').on('click', function () {
    dataTables.columns(4).search("Rejected","Approved").draw();
});
```

The javascript code work well for the #onprogreess button, because it only search for one value `Open`. How to make it works with two value search?

(#closed button supposed to show record with `Rejected` or `Done` Status)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To search **multiple values** from **single column** you can use **pipeline** as below:

```
dataTable.columns(4).search("Rejected|Done", true, false, true).draw();
```

You have to pass four parameters as below:

1. **Input:** Search string to apply to the table
2. **Regx:** Treat as a regular expression `(true)` or not `(default, false)`.
3. **Smart:** Perform smart search (default, true) or not (false). See below for a description of smart searching.
4. **CaseInsen:** Do case-insensitive matching (default, true) or not (false).

[More details](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search())

Answer (score 1):

var table = $('#example').DataTable();

table
    .columns( 4 )
    .search("")
    .draw();